# PostgreSQL check if value exists in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to find a solution in PostgreSQL of how I can add to the output of the query extra column with value if id exists in another table or not:

I need several things:

1. Do a join between two tables
2. Add a new column into the result output where I check if exists in the third table or not

My tables:

- announcement
- author
- chapter

`announcement` table

`| id | author_id | date | group_id | ... |`

`author` table

`| id | name | email | ... |`

`chapter` table

`| id | announcement_id | ... |`

This is what I have now. I did a left outer join and it works as I expected:

```
select announcement.id, announcement.date, author.id as publisher_id, author.name as publisher_name
from announcement 
left outer join author 
on announcement.author_id = author.id
where announcement.group_id = 123 and announcement.date >= '2022-06-01'::date;
```

with output:

```
| id | date       | publisher_id | publisher_name |
| 1  | 2020-07-01 | 12           | John           |
| 2  | 2020-07-04 | 123          | Arthur         |
```

Now I can't find a solution of how to add an extra column `with_chapters` to the query response, where I will check `if announcement.id exists in chapter table under announcement_id column`.

For example, chapter table can have such data:

```
| id | announcement_id |
| 1  | 1               |
| 2  | 1               |
| 3  | 1               |
```

So we see that some announcements can appear in chapters several times (so i'm looking for at least 1 match). And some announcements doesn't have chapters at all.

Output finally should be like that:

```
| id | date       | publisher_id | publisher_name | with_chapters |
| 1  | 2020-07-01 | 12           | John           | true          |
| 2  | 2020-07-04 | 123          | Arthur         | false         |
```

Thanks a lot for any help :)

Comment: _"... on release.publisher_id = author.id ..."_ Where is the `release.publisher_id` expression coming from?

Comment: It's a typo, changed description, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `EXISTS (subquery)` is usually used in the WHERE clause, it returns an ordinary Boolean and so can be used in the select list.

```
SELECT blah1, blah2, 
       EXISTS (select 1 from chapter where chapter.announcement_id=announcement.id) as with_chapter
FROM ...
```